# [How to run code by using cmd from sublime text 3 ]

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am a newbie in Python, and have a problem. When I code Python using `Sublime Text 3` and run directly on it, it does not find some Python library which I already imported. I Googled this problem and found out Sublime Text is just a Text Editor.

I already had code in Sublime Text 3 file, how can I run it without this error?

**For example:**

> 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'.

I think it should be run by `cmd` but I don't know how.

Comment: Your python interpreter doesn't have the modules installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what OS you are using this is easy. On Windows you can press win + r, then type `cmd`. This will open up a command prompt. Then, type in `pip install matplotlib`. This will make sure that your module is installed. Then, navigate to the folder which your code is located in. You can do this by typing in `cd Documents` if you first need to get to your documents and then for each subsequent folder.

Then, try typing in `python` and hitting enter. If a python shell opens up then type `quit()` and then type `python filename.py` and it will run.

If no python shell opens up then you need to change your environment variables. Press the windows key and pause break at the same time, then click on Advanced system settings. Then press Environment Variables. Then double click on Path. Then press New. Then locate the installation folder of you Python install, which may be in  `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36` Now put in the path and press ok. You should now be able to run python from your command line.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text default build system for python is "Python", which uses the "python" alias.

So if you'd like to use python3 for instance, you have to create a new build system.

Go to Tools > Build system > New build system...

There you have a command to specify, use the binary you'd like to be used by sublimeText, like so :

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3.7", "-u", "$file"]
}
```

Save the file to `python[X].sublime-build`, [X] being the version you'd like to use.

Now in your source file, specify the build system to that version of python.

To test that sublime text is using the interpreter you chose, you can use this code :

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

Check this for more informations : https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

Comment: @LePhucNguyen if you like that answer please vote it up, and click the little v sign left of the answer to reward me for my efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run it from your terminal once you have writen your script ?

You can also install a Python build system :
- Open sublime and go to tools->build system -> new build system

## Save this code in the file:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "python $file_name<inputf.in>outputf.in",
"selector": "source.python",
"working_dir": "$file_path"
```

}

- save it with any name say “whatEverYourWant”
- Now again go to tools -> build system and choose “whatEverYourWant”
- Run this using ctrl+shift+B or cmb+P

You can also install "Pycharm" if you are only working with Python. It is an amazing IDE.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I will try this IDE

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools>build system > new build system
and then copy and paste this code in it

```
    {
    "shell_cmd": "start cmd /k python $file_name",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
    }
```

Save it whatever you like without erasing the extention(.sublime-build)

and then write a python script, go to tools>build system and select the build system you just created.

then run your python script by going to tools>build
or ctrl+b and you will see that your python script will run in the command prompt.

By this way you can get input from the user.

Hope that this helps